# CSS Vertical Align Placeholder Text

Tags: css, styling

I'm trying to vertically align the place holder for a text input box.

I've got the `::--webkit` and `:--moz` rules going, and they're working for other stylings, but not vertically aligning...

I've tried `vertical-align: middle;` in the webkit rules, and under the `.input` itself. I've also tried `line-height: <same as the input box height>`

[jsfiddle.net/s3vpgxqg/](http://jsfiddle.net/s3vpgxqg/)

Can anyone see the simple thing I'm missing??

Thank you!!

Comment: Weird! I'm using Chrome also...

Comment: If you expand it to a larger height, where does the placeholder appear?

Comment: With a larger height it appears in the middle, but definitely not at 60px, and at the larger height I can't `vertical-align: top;` either (not that I want to): http://jsfiddle.net/dfuobnnn/ Is the text vertically aligned: top for you in this fiddle?

Comment: No, it is not working. I think I was mistaken; the placeholder only appeared to be aligned correctly. I will try and find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

One option is change the font formatting placeholder for input (the placeholder inherits the formatting).

https://jsfiddle.net/rwh6hkc6/

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.email.input {
  text-indent: 40px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Ultra-Light", "Helvetica Neue Ultra Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFCF6B;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: #B1B1B1;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color: #B1B1B1;
   opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color: #B1B1B1;
   opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color: #B1B1B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="email input" name="email" placeholder="enter your email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you run code snippet, the placeholder is not vertically aligned

Comment: This is because the top and bottom spacing varies depending on the font. Just check with the padding top and bottom

Comment: the point is that the placeholder font size is different from input font size.